# Cant get a response from API Rest call with Powershell script

Tags: powershell

Im trying to send an API call to X and then the response will trigger some other things.

The issue i have is that im not getting any response in the ISE.

When im sending manually with fiddler/postman i get a response.

Im sending a simple post :

```
$Json = '{"Headers_In_Here"}}'

$Post = Invoke-WebRequest 'http://Server_URL' -Method Post -Body $Json -ContentType 'application/json'
```

Comment: Your questions would look much better with a little [Mark Down](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Not really sure what we can tell you as we cannot test ourselves. What is in `$post`. There should be something there.

Comment: Hi Matt, Im testing on local server so ... thats the info i can give.

Comment: The JSON in your sample code is malformed (there's a spurious closing bracket). And as Matt already said: what is the actual value of `$Post`? That's about all the assistance we can provide given that little information.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ConvertTo-Json .

```
$Post = Invoke-WebRequest 'http://Server_URL' -Method Post -Body $Json -ContentType 'application/json' | ConvertTo-Json
```